# Grep command Linux ordering of source string and target string

Tags: linux, shell, grep

Grep command syntax is as:

```
grep "literal_string" filename --> search from string in filename.
```

So I am assuming the order of is like this

```
-- keyword(grep) --> string to be searched --> filename/source string and command is interpreted from left to right.
```

My question is how the commands such as this got processed:

```
ps -ef | grep rman
```

Do the order is optional? 
How grep is able to know that source is on left and not on right? Or I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

When using Unix Pipes, most system commands will take the output from the previous command (to the left of the pipe ) and then pass the output onto the command to the right of the pipe.

The order is important when using grep with or without a pipe.

Thus

```
grep doberman /file/about/dogs
```

is the same as

```
cat /file/about/dogs | grep doberman
```

See Pipes on http://linuxcommand.org/lts0060.php for some more information.

Answer (score 0):

As step further down from Kyle's answer regarding pipes is that most shell commands read their input from `stdin` and write their output to `stdout`. Now many of the commands will also allow you to specify a filename to read from or write too, or allow you to redirect a file to `stdin` as input and redirect the commands `stdout` to a file. But regardless how you specify what to read, the command process input from it's `stdin` and provides output on `stdout` (errors on `stderr`). `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are the designation of file descriptors `0, 1 & 2`, respectively.

This basic function is what allows command to be `piped` together. Where a `pipe` (represented by the `|` character) does nothing more that take the `stdout` from the first command (on left) and direct it to the next commands `stdin`. As such, yes, the order is important.

Another point to remember is that each piped process is run in its own subshell. Put another way, each `|` will spawn another shell to run the following command in. This has implications if you are relying on the environment of one process for the next.

Hopefully, these answers will give you a better feel for what is taking place.